# Use Guzzle 6 Concurrent call and keep track of extra parameters

Tags: php, concurrency, promise, guzzle, guzzle6

So im using Guzzle 6 to make indeterminate concurrent api calls, but one of the things I want to do it keep track of which array value the promise is currently processing since I originally process the api calls based on database query result. And after that I want to update the value back into the database with whatever I get back from the api.

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client();

$requests = function () {
    $uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8126/guzzle-server/perf';
    foreach($database_result as $res) {

        /*the res array contains 
        ['id' => 'db id', 'query' => 'get query array'];
        */

        $url = $uri . '?' . http_build_query($res['query']);

        yield new Request('GET', $url);
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(), [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        /**
         * HERE i want to be able to somehow 
         * retrieve the current responses db id
         * this way I can obviously update anything 
         * i want on the db side
         */
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
        /**
         * HERE i want to be able to somehow 
         * retrieve the current responses db id
         * this way I can obviously update anything 
         * i want on the db side
         */
    },
]);

// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
$promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool of requests to complete.
$promise->wait();
...
```

Any help with this would be amazing. I want to get advice on how to best approach this situation. I would prefer to do it in a smart, logical manner.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured this out.

Basically

```
    $requests = function () {
    $uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8126/guzzle-server/perf';
    foreach($database_result as $key => $res) {

        /*the res array was updated to be  
        ['id' => 'get query array'];
        */

        $url = $uri . '?' . http_build_query($res);

        //here is the key difference in change
        yield $key => new Request('GET', $url);
    }
};
```

Now later the index in the pool functionality will contain the index you want.

Hope this helps.

Reference: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/1203